# How to return all whole positive values for a+b = c+d while a,b,c, and d are not equal to each other?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, return, equation

Is there a way I can find all the values between certain parameter such as (1,10) that satisfy a+b = c+d while a,b,c, and d are not equal to each other.

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
var d;
function findValues (lowerbound, upperbound){
if ((a + b) === (c + d) && (a != b != c != d)) {
//some code
return(values)
}
}
findValues(1,10);
```

So if I insert 1 into the lower bound and ten into the upper bound it will return all values that meat the conditions in a sorted fashion.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in your code block. You aren't doing anything to assign a, b, c or d? Like what is supposed to be a, would it be lowerBound? What would b be, lowerbound + 1? How about c and d?  Additionally you are doing assignments, missing elements. Is this a real attempt or just dumping blank code to see who picks it up for you?

Comment: it looks like a subset sum problem, where a set of numbers should get a certain sum and another set should get the same. please add some examples and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using the assignment operator (`=`) in the `if` statement when you are trying to test for equality.

Replace it with the strict equality comparison (`===`).

```
if ((a + b) === (c + d) && (a != b != c != d))
```

Put your function in a loop where you modify the variables, and return true/false based on the logic above.